# Export maven project from Eclipse without target

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have a Maven project in Eclipse.

I'd like to export this project to a zip file (to transfer it to someone). It's easy and working with the "File \ Export \ General \ Archive File" menu.

Is there a way to exclude the target directory from the exported zip?
I need everything else: pom.xml, .project, src, ... , but not the target dir. The target dir sometimes are very big :(

The best would be, if it could be done from Eclipse, not with Maven.

Comment: Well, execute a *mvn clean* before exporting it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Export \ General \ Archive File >> click next >> expand your project (tree)>> deselect "target"